# Update JAVA Security Provider on/before Mule Start Up

Tags: java, mule, fips

To Enable **Mule** In **FIPS** mode according to mule documentation security providers need to be updated in  'java.security'  file. But I want to do this task programmatically on/before **Mule** startup ?